# Python NamedTuple factory method

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a class

```
class Instruction(NamedTuple):
    function: str
    argument_register_1: str
    argument_register_2: str
    result_register: str
```

and class that extends it:

```
class OrderedInstruction(Instruction):
    order: int

    @classmethod
    def from_instruction(cls, instruction: Instruction, order: int):
        return cls(instruction.function,
                   instruction.argument_register_1,
                   instruction.argument_register_2,
                   instruction.result_register,
                   order)
```

but the problem is when I try to call `OrderedInstruction.from_instruction(instruction, 0)` , I get the exception

```
TypeError: __new__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

And I don't know why. I can't debug it because I don't see the call to `__new__`. Can anyone tell me how to create/use `OrderedInstruction.from_instruction(instruction, number)`?

Comment: ``OrderedInstruction.__new__`` is ``Instruction.__new__``; ``__new__`` is not recreated when subclassing. Note that NamedTuples are generally not intended to be extended when subclassing - ["Subclassing is not useful for adding new, stored fields."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Extending named tuples via subclassing breaks certain feature relevant for substituting base and child (LSP), e.g. the length for unpacking. Is there a reason why you use inheritance instead of composition?

Comment: "Extending named tuples via subclassing breaks certain feature relevant for substituting base and child (LSP), e.g. the length for unpacking" - I didn't know that. I guess I'm just gonna use composition. Big thanks for help!

Comment: If you don't necessarily need a tuple, you may want to take a look at dataclasses or the ``attrs`` third-party library.